# forcing tensorflow to use matrix multiply for convolution

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

Does anyone know how to force tensorflow to use matrix multiply for convolutions?

It seems that there is a way using GEMM but I'm not sure exactly how to enable this or if Tensorflow has it's own GEMM.